# What does 'op' exactly mean in an submit button?

Tags: 7, forms

In the form_state['values']['op'] = t('Save');

What does 'op' exactly mean and do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's shorthand for the word `operation`.

It doesn't 'do' anything as such, it's the name assigned to all submit inputs so that the form processor can identify which button has been pressed (and perhaps fire off different submit handlers based on that).

And it looks like it's [gone in Drupal 8](https://drupal.org/node/852520) (in favour of `$form_state['triggering_element']`), so enjoy it while you can :)

Comment: Nope, not gone anywhere. That issue is not closed yet after almost 8 years. And the users who use browser translation feature to translate pages (and forms) can't submit forms. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2024, the best way to access the 'operation' in a form is to use `$form_state->getFormObject()->getOperation()`.

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityForm.php/function/EntityForm%3A%3AgetOperation/10